# Repurpose Google Search Appliance

Tags: google-search-appliance

I want to repurpose my GSA. But I can't do anything, it asks me for a password before it shows me a bios menu screen or something else.

- "After Configuring memory",
- "Initializing iDrac"
- A GSA loading screen...
- "Caution NVRAM_CLR jumper is installed on Systemboard" ...
- "Two Processors " ...
- "System Memory Size: 96G RAM" ...

and then it displays:

```
Type the password and

 - press Enter to leave password security enabled.
 - press Ctrl + Enter to disable password security

Enter password: _
```

It seems that the password disable jumper has no effect…
Any clues?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it a T4 or T5 ? If this is unclear you can post the service tag

Answer (score 1):

Only Google Support can unlock it.  You will need to contact them and allow remote access to the unit.